# Perform jQuery action when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the basis of my menu working, where when I click a menu element, it opens (similar to JQuery accordion), and when I click on another element in the menu, the previously opened menu closes and the newly clicked on opens.  Here's what it looks like:

[image: first opened item]

Now, I'm trying to implement functionality to close the currently opened menu if it is clicked again.  I'm using the `slideUp();` method, but having a hard time figuring out where to put the additional code for the 2nd click on the same element.

Here's what I have:

**navigation.html.erb**

```
<!-- menu links -->
      <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">

        <div class="menu_section">
          <h3>General</h3>
          <ul class="nav side-menu">
            <li><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
              <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
              <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                <li><a href="general_elements.html">General Elements</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Data Presentation <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
              <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                <li><a href="chartjs.html">Chart JS</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**custom.js**

```
var URL = window.location,
  $BODY = $('body'),
  $MENU_TOGGLE = $('#menu_toggle'),
  $SIDEBAR_MENU = $('#sidebar-menu'),
  $SIDEBAR_FOOTER = $('.sidebar-footer'),
  $LEFT_COL = $('.left_col'),
  $RIGHT_COL = $('.right_col'),
  $NAV_MENU = $('.nav_menu'),
  $FOOTER = $('footer');

var setContentHeight = function () {
    // reset height
    $RIGHT_COL.css('min-height', $(window).height());

    var bodyHeight = $BODY.height(),
        leftColHeight = $LEFT_COL.eq(1).height() + $SIDEBAR_FOOTER.height(),
        contentHeight = bodyHeight < leftColHeight ? leftColHeight : bodyHeight;

    // normalize content
    contentHeight -= $NAV_MENU.height() + $FOOTER.height();

    $RIGHT_COL.css('min-height', contentHeight);
};


    $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('a').on('click', function(ev) {
        var $li = $(this).parent();

        if ($li.hasClass('.active')) {
          $li.removeClass('active');
          $('ul:first', $li).slideUp(function(){
              setContentHeight();
          });
        } else {
          $li.addClass('active');
          $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('.side-menu li').not($li).removeClass('active');
          $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('.side-menu li').not($li).find('.child_menu').removeClass('active').slideUp();
          $('ul:first', $li).slideDown(function(){
              setContentHeight();
          });
        }
    });
```

Comment: `($li.hasClass('.active'))` needs to be `($li.hasClass('active'))`

Comment: @theblindprophet when I make that change, me menu item expands then closes automatically...

Comment: Post a fiddle if possible,

Comment: It would probably be a lot easier to use `toggleClass` and `slideToggle`, and let jQuery deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `if ($li.hasClass('.active'))` to `if ($li.hasClass('active'))` and that should resolve the issue. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/vsLp3kgd/). I have created an empty setContentHeight function to make it work.

Comment: This works for me. I have updated my answer with a fiddle.

Comment: I added what my `setContentHeight` function looks like... could that be the issue?